# How to set the text of a swing label, using a string variable as the name of the label?

Tags: java

I have a string such as:

```
String labelName = "lblColaStock";
```

Which is also the name of a Swing label. I would like to `setText()` on this label. Something like:

```
labelName.setText("some text");
```

However, the labels and strings can be different each execution. One time it may be:

```
String labelName = "lblColaDietStock";
```

And now the label I want to change is called `lblColaDietStock`.

How can I change a label's text, using a string variable as the label name?

Comment: What did you plan to have in your map. You are putting the label name and an Integer in the map with the labelName as the key. Did you plan to have the Swing JLabel in the map?

Comment: You can't set the text of an Integer. You want to set the text of a JLabel. So the map should contain JLabels, not Integers. Also, the keys of the map are Strings. So calling get(1) doesn't make sense: 1 is not a String, and is not the name of your label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can understand your question you need to create mapping where keys are numbers and values are labels.

Code will be like that:

```
JLabel label = //label variable 
Map<Integer, JLabel> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, label);
map.get(1).setText("label text");
```

In your code you have 2 mistakes, first is you missed up keys and values in map declaration, even if you did not do it you get String from map and try to invoke method `setText()` on it. `myMap.get(1).setText("some text");` this is second mistake.

Comment: Do you really need the `map` as OP says the `name` of the `label` is same to the `String` ?

Comment: To me, this has the same effect as `label.setText("label text");`. But I want to do `lblColaStock.setText("label text");`. But `lblColaStock` is currently in string form. I want to use this `string.setText`...

Answer (score -2):

Probably you mean something like this:

```
Jlabel jLabel = new JLabel();
String labelName = "lblColaStock";

HashMap<String,JLabel> myMap = new HashMap();
myMap.put(labelName,jLabel);

myMap.get(labelName).setText("some text");
```

Comment: Do you really need the `map` as OP says the `name` of the `label` is same to the `String` ?

Comment: @Shubhendu Right now I have no clue what the OP wants to do. Hoping he come back with some more explanation about his problem.

Comment: @PeterMmm Ive updated question. I hope its clearer now